# Retrieving value from static extension XAML

Tags: xaml

How do I retrieve the value (Int32.MaxValue) from the static extension:

```
    <x:Static
        x:Key="TooltipTimeout"
        Member="s:Int32.MaxValue"
        />
```

...

`<blablalba TooltipService.ShowDuration="{StaticResource TooltipTimeout}"/>` <-- this does not work by the way

Answer (score 1):

Methinks you're doing something else wrong.  Slap this in kaxaml:

```
<Page
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
  <x:Static x:Key="Derp" Member="sys:Int32.MaxValue"/>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>  
  <TextBlock 
    ToolTipService.ShowDuration="{StaticResource Derp}" 
    ToolTip="Derp" Text="Herp"  />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Mod tested, mother approved.

If I had to guess, I think you're not defining your xml namespace for Int32 correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, You can access static member directly, like this,

```
<TextBlock TooltipService.ShowDuration="{x:Static s:Int32.MaxValue}"/>
```

However, you cannot do the same in Silverlight, as it wouldn't work. In silveright, you've to write a wrapper class,  like this,

```
public class StaticMemberAccess
{
      public int Int32Max { get { return Int32.MaxValue; } }
      //define other wrapper propeties here, to access static member of .Net or your classes
}
```

Then do this in XAML,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <local:StaticMemberAccess x:Key="SMA"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock TooltipService.ShowDuration="{Binding Source={StaticResource SMA}, Path=Int32Max}"/>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind to your resource by setting it as the Source of your binding:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource TooltipTimeout}}
```