# Binding to SystemColors in Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have following code in WPF XAML and want it to be converted to Silverlight 4:

```
<Setter
    Property="Background"
    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
<Setter>
```

Unfortunately, Silverlight does not support `x:Static`.

Does anybody know how to port it properly without code behind, XAML-only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you cannot access Static properties like that,you've to define your own "wrapper" class that will wrap the static properties, something like this:

```
public class StaticMemberAccess
{
      public ResourceKey WindowBrushKey { return SystemColors.WindowBrushKey; }
      //define other wrapper propeties here, to access static member of .Net or your classes
}
```

Then do this in XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <local:StaticMemberAccess x:Key="SMA"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Setter
    Property="Background"
    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource SMA}, Path=WindowBrushKey}" />
<Setter>
```

Hope, it gives you some idea. :-)

See this also:

[Retrieving value from static extension XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303682/retrieving-value-from-static-extension-xaml)